# C++ - Eclipse - Organize include

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have defined a class `Executer` splited in `Executer.hpp` and `Executer.cpp`.

In `Executer.hpp` there is the code:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Executer> mInstance;
static std::once_flag mOnceFlag;
```

In `Executer.cpp` there is the code:

```
std::unique_ptr<Executer> Executer::mInstance;
std::once_flag Executer::mOnceFlag; // without this apparently
    // useless line of code, the program using this shared lib
    // claims: undefined reference to `Executer::mOnceFlag'
```

After that I try to let eclipse organize my imports.

What I get is:

```
//------------------------------- Executer.hpp
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

namespace std {
struct once_flag;
} /* namespace std */
//------------------------------- Executer.cpp
#include "Executer.hpp"    
#include <mutex>
```

What I expect (and also is compiled correctly):

```
//------------------------------- Executer.hpp
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
//------------------------------- Executer.cpp    
#include "Executer.hpp"
```

1. Why is Eclipse behaving in that way?
2. Can I configure Eclipse in such a way that I get *my way* of organizing the includes (I have seen the many options, but I got things worst)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Eclipse behaving in that way?

The type of a static data member is not required to be complete at the point of the data member's declaration. That is, the declaration will compile with the type having been just forward-declared, not defined.

The default settings for "Organize Includes" try to minimize the number of headers that are included in other headers, to speed up compile times, so when a forward declaration of a type is sufficient, it prefers to create one rather than to include the header than defines the type.

> Can I configure Eclipse in such a way that I get my way of organizing the includes (I have seen the many options, but I got things worst)

Unchecking `Forward declare classes, structs and unions` in `Preferences | C/C++ | Code Style | Organize Includes` should give you the behaviour you desire.